# Generic method call on interface based on JSON message

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following JSON:

```json
{
    "metadata": {
        "MESSAGE_TYPE": "PersonCreated"
    },
    "data": {
        "name": "Peter",
        "age": 33
    }
}
```

This message is received by listening to Azure Event Hub and getting a [ProcessEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.processor.processeventargs?view=azure-dotnet). I receive a bunch of these messages, and they should all do something different.

What I've done is create a class (`PersonCreated` for example) for each of my messages, and then placed those in the same folder using the same namespace. I also have a `BaseMessage` class with that same namespace.

In my code, I then deserialize to a known type based on the `BaseMessage` namespace and the event's `MESSAGE_TYPE`:

```cs
var ns = typeof(BaseMessage).Namespace;
var type = Type.GetType(ns + "." + messageType);

dynamic message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(payload, type)!;

await _processingService.ProcessMessage(message);
```

What this allows me to do, is create an interface like this:

```cs
public interface IProcessingService
{
    Task ProcessMessage(PersonCreated message);
    Task ProcessMessage(AnimalCreated message);
    Task ProcessMessage(LoanCreated message);
}
```

By passing in my `dynamic` to the interface method, I have essentially made everything generic. I no longer have to do something like this:

```cs
if(MESSAGE_TYPE == "PersonCreated")
{´
    var message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PersonCreated>(payload);
    await _processingService.ProcessMessage(message);
} else if(.........)
```

Obviously there are some downsides to this, such as if a message arrives with no known interface method or class, it will fail in runtime.

What is this type of "generic message processing" (as I call it) called? Where can I learn some best practises? I think this is quite a nice alternative to using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance()`.

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. In my experience, almost every usage of dynamic is just a way to hide bad practice, and I try to avoid it. In this case, I think there are better ways.

Comment: Also having `IProcessingService` processing multiple types is a bit of a code smell to me. Objects like that should really be responsible for processing single types (see the single responsibility principle)

Comment: @DavidG I completely agree, which is why I would like to read up on some best practises. I've seen other people do this, that's where I got the idea, but I never really found the term to search for to learn more. Feel free to elaborate and reply with your answer if you think there's a better way (that's still generic). MESSAGE_TYPE maps directly to a class in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for "[Polymorphic serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)".

The System.Text.Json uses a `$type`-field instead of your `MESSAGE_TYPE` to identify the class, but the idea is the same. This should let you write code like:

```
var message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseMessage>(payload);
```

With the message actually being a `PersonCreated`, `AnimalCreated`, or whatever.

To then call the correct process method you could use the [Visitor Patten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This should provide the same degree of flexibility with only marginally more code. And it would avoid `dynamic` and all the problems that could cause.

For example:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(PersonMessage), "PersonMessage")]
public abstract class MessageBase
{
    public abstract void Accept(IMessageVisitor visitor) ;
}

public class PersonMessage : MessageBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override void Accept(IMessageVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public interface IMessageVisitor
{
    public void Visit(PersonMessage message);
}

public class MyMessageVisitor : IMessageVisitor
{
    public void Visit(PersonMessage message) => Console.WriteLine($"Visited person {message.Name} Age {message.Age}");
}

[Test]
public void SerializePolymorphicMessage()
{
    MessageBase message = new PersonMessage() {Name = "Tom Bombadil" , Age = 4321};
    var messageString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MessageBase>(messageString);

    var visitor = new MyMessageVisitor();
    result.Accept(visitor);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the right thing. Thanks. The code you listed doesn't work, though. There's no Deserialize method that takes the type, string payload, and Type type, unfortunately.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Oups, fixed.

Comment: Yep, that does work, however, when using the visitor pattern on top of that, it calls the Accept method on the base class. Not the child's Accept method

Comment: @MortenMoulder The `Accept`-method should be virtual. If the child's overriden Accept method is not called you probably do not have a child object. Check that you have added the `JsonDerivedType` attribute, and see the linked example to ensure the serialization step does what it is supposed to.

Comment: I've tried with both abstract and virtual. I do have JsonDerivedType attribute on my base class. One for each message type. I just get `Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported`

Comment: And when I remove abstract from the base class, it just keeps calling the base class' Accept method.

Comment: My JSON doesn't have the $type property - could that be why?

Comment: Yep that was it. The deserialization error was because it was abstract. Hmm I don't like this pattern. It can still fail at runtime, because you need to remember to inherit from the base class, you need to remember to override the Accept method (because it's virtual), and you need to remember to add the `JsonDerivedType` parameter to the base class.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Added an example to show the pattern. And yes, you need you need to remember to add the attribute. Unit tests is the best solution for that. But If you make the base class abstract you are forced to implement `Accept`, and if your message sender uses the base type there is no risk forgetting to implement the base type.

Comment: Appreciate it. The main issue is having to modify the JSON and add the attribute, which seems like unnecessary work. Something the deserializer should be able to do. An extension method that adds a Type as parameter might be possible to create. I know I'm deserializing to the base class and I know the type already, so why not give us the option to do it without the attribute? Maybe that's a feature request :) Thanks

Comment: @MortenMoulder Json.Net includes the full typename as the `$type` value. But that causes problems if you ever move or rename a class, and there are also security problems. So I really prefer the attribute approach.